# Inline Javascript: Is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have many view templates where i have inline javascript specific to that view.

for eg:

```
app/views/something/index.html.haml
.some-id
  %h4 Something

#this javascript is not reused anywhere. Used only in this view
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some-id').addClass('something')
  })
```

Is it a good practice to have the views like above?

It is definitely a pain to maintain inline javascript across multiple views. So i started moving them slowly into one single javascript file. But i am not sure if that's a good thing because, all the javascript will now get executed for all the pages.

So which is the best place to put view specific javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are worried about page load time, you should use something like [loadjs](https://github.com/guidomb/loadjs). It is just not maintainable to be place JS in your views like that. For super simple projects then maybe, but in general you should stay away from it.

Another thing to note is that browsers will cache your javascript when it is loaded from a file. They cannot do this when it is inline because the HTML is rendered every page load. So you probably are looking at an overall performance loss when doing it inline, even without loadjs.